# NHibernate - ISession.Clear() vs. ISession.GetSessionImplementation().PersistenceContext.Clear()

Tags: session, caching, nhibernate, lazy-loading

What would be the main difference between doing a `session.Clear()` vs. `session.GetSessionImplementation().PersistenceContext.Clear()`?

In my case, ideally, I would only clear the cache for a context switch in my code because I want to prevent lazyloading objects from previous context. And also, I wouldn't get the error that I am getting:

> NHibernate.LazyInitializationException : Initializing[...#34]-failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: [...], no session or session was closed

Answer (score 0):

`session.Clear()` clears PersistenceContext and also cancels all pending actions (saves, updates and deletions).

Comment: Sorry for necromanc-ing this comment, but would `Session.Clear()` also prevent all `Future` previously opened from loading ? NHibernate is throwing No session exception for me if I try to `.Value` a Future after `Session.Clear()`.